# Bootstrap Multiselect (David Stutzs) - Display 10 options without scroll

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have developed a multiselect dropdown using [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) version and wanted to display 10 options (assuming i have more than 10 options) on click of it. I have used `maxHeight` option to achieve this, however, is not correct solution as it displays 9 options sometimes and 10 options on another page.

Here is my code -

```
MultiSelect.setMultiSelect = function MultiSelect$setMultiSelect(input) {
    var inputField = jQuery('#' + input);
    try
    {
        inputField
                .multiselect({
                    maxHeight : 400,
                    includeSelectAllOption : false,
                    enableFiltering : false,
                    buttonWidth : '100%',
                    dropUp : true
                    }
                });
    } catch (ex)
    {}
}
```